# Как получить кол-во вхождений значения в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript

Этот алгоритм считает кол-во вхождений элемента в массиве

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 8, 4];

function howMany(array, value) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        if (array[i] == value)
            n++;
    return n;
}

console.log(howMany(numbers, 3)); // -> 0
console.log(howMany(numbers, 4)); // -> 3
console.log(howMany(numbers, 5)); // -> 0
console.log(howMany(numbers, 6)); // -> 0
```

Должен ведь быть соответствующий метод для массива?

Comment: В самом деле должен? `numbers.filter(x => x === value).length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ответ free_ze в комментариях решил рпоблему

```
array.filter(x => x === value).length
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно прикрутить замыкание, чтобы сохранить результаты первого прохода по массиву и переиспользовать их.

```js
function howMany(arr) {
  const map = arr.reduce((c, item) => (c[item]=(c[item]||0) + 1, c), {});
  
  return num => map[num];
}

const data = [1, 5, 4, 3, 4, 6, 4, 7, 1];

console.log(howMany(data)(4)); // 3

const howManyInData = howMany(data);
console.log(howManyInData(1), howManyInData(4)); // 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = [2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 8, 4];

Array.prototype.howMany = function(value) {
    return this.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return curr === value ? prev+1 : prev
    }, 0);
}

console.log(numbers.howMany(3));
console.log(numbers.howMany(4));
console.log(numbers.howMany(5));
console.log(numbers.howMany(6));
```